# notable image quality loss when importing from iOS library

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using the iPad photo library (camera roll) to import some images, and place them in a UIImageView I create using the alloc method. but when the images are shown there is a great image quality loss. For example, in the library there is an image with a river which is very sharp, pixel by pixel, but when I import it it loses at least half of the pixels. This is the code for importing the image:

```
- (IBAction) useCameraRoll: (id)sender
{
    @autoreleasepool {

if ([self.popoverController isPopoverVisible]) {
    [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

} else{

    }{
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
         UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum])
    {
        @autoreleasepool {

        UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =
        [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        imagePicker.sourceType =
        UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                  (NSString *) kUTTypeImage,
                                  nil];

        imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;

        self.popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                                  initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];
        }
        popoverController.delegate = self;

        [self.popoverController 
         presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender
         permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp
         animated:YES];


        newMedia = NO;


    }}
}
}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:true];
@autoreleasepool {

NSString *mediaType = [info
                       objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {
    UIImage *image = [info
                      objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];

    image1.image = image;
    if (newMedia)
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image,
                                       self,  
                                           @selector(image:finishedSavingWithError:contextInfo:),
                                       nil);
}
else if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie])
{
    // Code here to support video if enabled
}}
}

-(void)image:(UIImage *)image
finishedSavingWithError:(NSError *)error
 contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
{
if (error) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle: @"Save failed"
                          message: @"Failed to save image"\
                          delegate: nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
}

-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{

}
```

And the quality difference (image zoomed in) but you can clearly see the difference even in small scale:

iOS library:

[image]

My UIImageView:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should use

```
UIImage *img = [info valueForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
```

to get the original Image.

Comment: you mean instead of UIImage *image = [info
                        objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage]; ??

Comment: Yes, works beautifully fine. even mine was ok in this way: UIImage *image = [info
                       objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

Comment: ...but there is no editing option, and I would like to keep the edited version!!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed a similar problem when working on a Universal app. Picking an image from the Photo Album on iPod touch with allowEditing=YES worked fine with no loss of quality, but on iPad the  UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage was only 320 pixels wide, resulting in a loss of quality, I think because the popover used for editing is only 320 pixels wide!

After much searching I came across [this code](http://cmgresearch.blogspot.co.il/2012/07/cropping-results-from.html) to crop the original image again using the User's crop settings from the dictionary, but I can't help feeling there's got to be a better way to handle this on the iPad